# How to remove the line from \gategroup command in quantikz

Tags: tikz-styles, quantikz

Within [quantikz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03842.pdf) package there's the possibility to wrap a circuit within a box, through the command

`\gategroup[]{}`

By default, such a group plots the perimeter. The options allow to make the perimeter continous or dashed.

However I would like to not have it at all. For example with the following attribute setting:

```
\gategroup[wires=1,steps=5,style={no line, rounded corners}, background]{}
```

Can someone explain me how can I overcome this problem, even by changing the package itself if necessary. Which I believe is [this one](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `draw=none` does the trick

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
& \gate{H} & \ctrl{1}\gategroup[2,steps=3,
style={rounded corners, draw=none, fill=blue!20, inner xsep=2pt},
background]{{\sc swap}} & \targ{} & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \qw \\
& \qw & \targ{} & \ctrl{-1} & \targ{} & \gate{H} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]